# Can't unzip Chef cookbooks on Windows Command Line - 'tar' not recognized

Tags: command-line, tar, chef-infra

Unfortunately stuck using Windows command line as opposed to Linux bash...

When installing chef cookbooks from command line using

```
knife cookbook site install COOKBOOK
```

the COOKBOOK.tar.gz file will download but won't extract.  How can I make this happen in Windows Command line?

The error messages received

`ERROR: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'

    ...

    STDERR: 'tar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

What do I need to do for the cookbook to automatically install as it normally should?

**EDIT**:  ADDITIONAL INFO:  cygwin & ruby are also installed.
The tar package is installed and can unzip files using

```
tar xvzf apt.tar.gz
```

Comment: Have you installed tar package (http://cygwin.com/packages/) in your cygwin? Can you run tar from cmd?

Comment: Yes, the tar package is installed and works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the PATH variable in Windows.

Ensure the PATH environment variable doesn't contain any spaces.

If there are spaces, remove them OR
move the paths applicable to your chef installation to the beginning of the PATH variable

```
D:\Programs\Git\cmd;D:\Programs\cygwin\bin;D:\Programs\chef\bin;RESTOFPATH
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have git windows installed then use the git bash shell